# How to remove unit from number and multiply the number

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a column of properties' land area in pandas dataframe. The land area is measured in both square meter and hectare. I want to use only the square meter as unit so I will need to convert hectare to square meter by multiplying the number by 10000. The original column looks like this (only showing the first ten):

```
    0       895m2
    1      52.9ha
    2      1229m2
    3         NaN
    4         NaN
    5         NaN
    6         NaN
    7         NaN
    8      2961m2
    9         NaN
    10        NaN
```

I've removed `ha` by writing this code: `df['Land area (m2)'].str.replace('ha','')` and I got this:

```
0       895m2
1        52.9
2      1229m2
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8      2961m2
9         NaN
10        NaN
```

So now my problem is how I'm gonna remove `m2` **AND** change the unit from hectare to square meter where needed **AND** convert the whole column into `float` at the same time? Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by values for multiple, remove missing values and multiple strings by [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
df['Land area (m2)'] = (df['Land area (m2)'].replace({'ha':'*10000','m2':'*1'}, regex=True)
                                            .dropna()
                                            .apply(pd.eval))
print (df)
    Land area (m2)
0            895.0
1         529000.0
2           1229.0
3              NaN
4              NaN
5              NaN
6              NaN
7              NaN
8           2961.0
9              NaN
10             NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm wondering what's the role of ```dropna()``` here?

Comment: @Ilovenoodles - It remove missing values for avoid error in `pd.eval`.